# Robolectric + Gradle Fails when initialized test

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, robolectric

I can't execute tests with Robolectric, when I try to execute the tests:

```
./gradlew test
```

I get the following exception:

```
com.Makeupalley.test.HomeRobolectricTest > initializationError FAILED
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/app/Activity
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
.
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.app.Activity
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
```

The test fails with any assert like this: **assertTrue(true).**

This is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/' }
    }
     dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
         classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:0.12.+'

    }
}

...

dependencies {
    compile('junit:junit:4.11') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }

 compile('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3') {
        exclude module: 'classworlds'
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        ...
    }    
}
```

Test File:

```
@Config(emulateSdk = 18)
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class HomeRobolectricTest {
    private TestActivity activity;

    public HomeRobolectricTest(){}

    @Before
    public void setup()  {
        activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(TestActivity.class).create().get();
    }

    @Test
    public void testInstanceActivity() throws Exception {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

...
}
```

Someone can help me our give me some guidelines?

If you need more information or all build.gradle file, I can post it.

build.gradle file: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d0f0bac71a0fb76f8454

Thanks

**UPDATE - Android section**

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 15
        versionCode 45
        versionName "1.4.210"
        testInstrumentationRunner     "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
        debug {
            runProguard false
            testCoverageEnabled = true
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {

    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }

    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            setRoot('src/test')
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a feeling that it has to do with saying `compile` instead of `testCompile` for the testing. Look at this website and see if it helps: http://www.peterfriese.de/android-testing-with-robolectric/

Comment: do you have android section in build.gradle?

Comment: Thanks for help. I used "androidTestCompile" instead of "compile" and the exception persists. I can't use "testCompile" because I get the following error:
Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'testCompile()'!Possible causes could be:- you are using Gradle version where the method is absent...

Comment: I post the android section

Comment: Did you forgot `apply plugin 'robolectric'`? After this you could change `compile` to `testCompile`

Comment: Other question why your target sdk is 15 but you're trying to emulate sdk 18. It should not break anything but something that I spotted

Answer (score 0):

Since the android gradle plugin version 1.1.0, there is support for unit testing so you can use testCompile in the gradle files. Turn it on with settings > gradle > experimental and update the gradle plugin version:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the following setup:

**app/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5"
    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4"
}
```

With Gradle verions below 2.5 it also did not work for me. Since they released a new version 2.5 a few days ago I gave it a try and it does solve the problem for me.

**gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.prooperties**

```
#Wed Apr 10 15:27:10 PDT 2013
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.5-all.zip
```